# How to complete Akka Http response with Stream and Custom Status Code

Tags: scala, http-status-codes, akka-stream, akka-http

I've got an akka-http application that uses akka-streams for data processing. So, it makes some sense to complete the request with `Source[Result, _]` to get backpressure across HTTP boundary for free.

Versions:

- akka-http 10.0.7
- akka-streams 2.5.2
- akka 2.5.2

This is the simplified version of the code, and it works just fine.

```
pathEnd { post { entity(asSourceOf[Request]) { _ =>
    complete {
        Source.single("ok")
    }
}}}
```

Since this enpoint is supposed to create and entity, instead of returning 200 OK to the requester I'd like to return 204 CREATED status code. However, I wasn't able to find a way to do that:

- `complete { Created -> source.single("ok") }` fails compilation with `Type mismatch, expected: ToResponseMarshallable, actual: (StatusCodes.Success, Source[String, NotUsed])`
- `complete { source.single((Created, "ok")) }` fails with `Type mismatch, expected: ToResponseMarshallable, actual: Source[(StatusCodes.Success, String), NotUsed]`
- `complete(Created) { Source.single("ok") }` fails with `Type mismatch, expected: RequestContext, actual: Source[String,NotUsed]`
- `complete(Created, Source.signle("ok")` fails with `too many arguments for method complete(m: => ToResponseMarshallable)`

It looks like [custom marshaller](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.7/scala/http/common/marshalling.html#custom-marshallers) might be a way to achieve that, but it'll basically mean I'll need one unmarshaller per endpoint, which isn't quite convenient or clear.

So, the question is, are there a (more convenient than custom unmarshaller) way to complete the request with `Source[_,_]` while also providing status code.

Comment: Can't you just send a `StatusCodes.Created` as the first parameter to `complete`?

Comment: @NimrodArgov Updated the question - in short either I'm doing something wrong, or it doesn't work as well. But thank you for suggestion!

Comment: I meant `complete(Created, Source.single("ok"))`

Comment: @NimrodArgov `too many arguments for method complete(m: => ToResponseMarshallable)`. Are we talking about the same `complete`? :) I'm using akka-http 1.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this problem and took the approach of using mapResponse to override the status code.  This is the simplest approach I've found.

```
mapResponse(_.copy(status = StatusCodes.Accepted)) {
  complete {
    Source.single("ok")
  }
}
```

The drawback of Ramon's answer is that you become responsible for both marshalling the stream (to a ByteString), and for the content negotiation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know (not sure when I could revisit this problem though)

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/route-directives/complete.html#complete):

```
complete(Created -> "bar")
```

If you want to provide some `Source` of data then construct the `HttpResponse` and pass it to `complete`:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Chunked
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentTypes
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.ChunkStreamPart

complete {

  val entity = 
    Chunked(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,
            Source.single("ok").map(ChunkStreamPart.apply))

  HttpResponse(status = Created, entity=entity)
}
```